# JavaScript Append a new object to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, javascript-objects

Hi trying to add a new object to the list of cars for particular user, below is my array of object called inventory. Ive used a find to get the user id which return.

I want to add  extra objects to the cars property i.e  {model: "Porsche",year: "2009"} to the user array when the user id  = 1

Is there a cleaner way of doing this without using push

```js
const inventory = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Paul",
    cars: [
      {
        model: "Ford",
        year: "1995",
      },
      {
        model: "BMW",
        year: "2010",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Simon",
    cars: [
      {
        model: "Vauxhall",
        year: "2022",
      },
      {
        model: "VW",
        year: "2001",
      },
    ],
  },
];


const found = inventory.find(element => element.id == 1);

//console.log(found)
const addNewObject = found.cars.concat({model: "Porsche",year: "2009"})
console.log(addNewObject)
```

Comment: What is wrong with push?

Comment: You are using `concat`,  you can use `unshift` . Don't know what's the problem with `push`

Comment: using spread operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the spread operator:

```
const addNewObject = [...found.cars, {model: "Porsche",year: "2009"}];
```

This will give you the same result as your code.

In case you want to know how to update the `inventory` in an immutable style (is this the reason why you don't like `push`?), you can use `map`:

```
const updatedInventory = inventory.map(item => 
 item.id === 1
   ? {...item, cars: [...item.cars, {model: "Porsche",year: "2009"}]}
   : item
);
```

Comment: yes wanted a immutable style solution thanks

Comment: great! if this is what you needed, please mark this questions as answered, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the array in-place, use [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Otherwise [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is the way to go:

```js
const newInventory = [...inventory, {model: "Porsche",year: "2009"}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and update the item that has an `id` of `1`.

```js
const inventory = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Paul",
    cars: [
      { model: "Ford", year: "1995" },
      { model: "BMW", year: "2010" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Simon",
    cars: [
      { model: "Vauxhall", year: "2022" },
      { model: "VW", year: "2001" },
    ],
  },
];

const updatedInventory = inventory.map((item) =>
  item.id === 1
    ? { ...item, cars: item.cars.concat({ model: "Porsche", year: "2009" }) }
    : item
);

console.log(updatedInventory);
```

If you want don't want to create a new array, then you can use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `map`.

```js
const inventory = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Paul",
    cars: [
      { model: "Ford", year: "1995" },
      { model: "BMW", year: "2010" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Simon",
    cars: [
      { model: "Vauxhall", year: "2022" },
      { model: "VW", year: "2001" },
    ],
  },
];

inventory.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.id === 1) {
    item.cars.push({ model: "Porsche", year: "2009" });
  }
});

console.log(inventory);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const inventory = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Paul",
    cars: [
      {
        model: "Ford",
        year: "1995",
      },
      {
        model: "BMW",
        year: "2010",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Simon",
    cars: [
      {
        model: "Vauxhall",
        year: "2022",
      },
      {
        model: "VW",
        year: "2001",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const addPropertyToCars=(id,newKeyValues)=>
inventory.map(item=>
item.id!==id ? item :{...item, cars:[...item.cars,newKeyValues]}
)


const newKeyValues={model: "Porsche",year: "2009"}

const newInventory=addPropertyToCars(1,newKeyValues)
```